# Get Matched array value in indexOf

Tags: javascript

I'm beginner of javascript and have a quick question.
Please refer to the below codes.

```js
var test1 = [1,2,3],
    test2 = [4,5,6],
    test3 = [7,8,9];

var urlsToMatch = [
  [test1, '/hello'], [test1, '/Bonjour'],
  [test2, '/Ohio'], [test3, '/Nice']
];

current_url = window.location.href;

urlsToMatch.forEach(function(item) {
        var matchedSeq = item[0];
        var matchPattern = item[1];
        if (current_url.indexOf(matchPattern) > -1) { 
           console.log(matchedSeq[0]);
        }
});
```

In this case, I just wanted to know what values are matched and if statements became true.
And I hope get matched 'urlsToMatch' array's key.
Hope to get 'test1' or 'test2' or 'test3'.
Could you please help me out to grow my skill? :) thanks.

Comment: Do `console.log(matchedSeq);` or `console.log(item[0]);` instead of `console.log(matchedSeq[0]);`

Comment: Arrays don't have keys, but numeric indices. `test1`, etc is not an index to `urlsTomatch`.